# To use different paths to access same resource in REST API

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Working with Spring-boot:MVC , REST API

Background: Model=Student >> Long age (one of the attributes of Student class)

Can I define two URL paths to access the age of a particular student? Example:

1. Access by id of student

`

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/age")
public ResponseEntity<String> getStudentAge(@PathVariable Long id) {
    String age = studentService.retrieveAgeById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(age, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

`

SQL query (using id ):

```
@Query("select d.id, d.age from Student d where d.id=:id")
String findAgeById(Long id);
```

2. Access age by name of Student

`

```
   @GetMapping("/{name}/age")
        public ResponseEntity<String>  getStudentAgeByName(@PathVariable String name) {
            String age = studentService.retrieveAgeByName(name);
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(age, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

`

SQL Query (using name):

```
@Query("select d.name, d.age from Student d where d.name=:name")
    String findAgeByName(String name);
```

This method is producing this error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Ambiguous handler methods mapped for '/2/age': {public
>   org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
>   com.example.restapi.controller.StudentController.getStudentAgeByName(java.lang.String),
>   public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
>   com.example.restapi.controller.StudentController.getStudentAge(java.lang.Long)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `/{name}/age` and `/{id}/age` are same path.
Here, `{name}` or `{id}` is a path variable.

So you are trying to do map two different handler method with the same path. That's why spring gives you error `Ambiguous handler methods mapped`

You can try this way to resolve this

```
@GetMapping("/age/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<String> getStudentAge(@PathVariable Long id) {
    String age = studentService.retrieveAgeById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(age, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@GetMapping("/age/name/{name}")
public ResponseEntity<String>  getStudentAgeByName(@PathVariable String name) {
     String age = studentService.retrieveAgeByName(name);
     return new ResponseEntity<String>(age, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But it's better to use request param for non identifer field like `name`

Comment: @SrikanthKb if you found any solution helpful upvote them also .

Comment: Pardon me, I forgot to respond to this. Thanks for the solution!